# Qual a diferença entre o <span> e a class?

Tags: css, xhtml

Enquanto estudando XHTML, entendi que o `<span>` é um elemento em linha. A `class` será um elemento em bloco.

Mas quando usar um e outro? Além deles, quando usar alguns elementos sabendo que existem outros parecidos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você está a misturar coisas diferentes. Um `span` é um elemento HTML inline, porém a `class` é um atributo de elementos como o `span`, `p`, `div` ou qualquer outro. 
Ou seja pode juntar-se o atributo `class` ao span para lhe dar classes de CSS.

Da mesma maneira que se pode fazer assim para mudar a côr para azul:

```
<span style="color: blue;">Este texto é azul</span>
```

O mesmo pode (e deve) ser feito usando classes CSS para poder ter as regras de CSS num ficheiro à parte que controla todos os elementos com uma certa class. Assim o exemplo em cima pode ser feito assim usando class:

CSS

```
.azul{ color: blue;}
```

HTML

```
<span class="azul">Este texto é azul também</span>
```

Este exemplo em cima é simples mas em páginas com centenas de spans não é prático escrever o stile ou mudar elemento a elemento, então usam-se class(es).

Outra grande vantagem que não tem a ver com o CSS é a possibilidade de selecionar grupos de elementos que partilhem a mesma class no DOM e aplicar-lhes outras regras ou mudá-los caso necessário. Isto pode ser feito com CSS, por exemplo usando `.azul:hover{ color: red;}` que muda a cor no caso de o mouse passar por cima, ou no caso de javascript (com ou sem biblioteca) onde se pode fazer:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.azul').innerHTML = 'Novo texto...';
```

e assim mudar o texto (conteudo) dos elemento que tenham essa classe, independentemente de serem span ou não.

Estes são exemplos bem simples mas no fundo é importante lembrar que o `span` é um elemento do DOM, e o `class` é um atributo de elementos do DOM que lhes dá classes CSS para poderem aplicar regras de CSS ao elemento; ou poderem ser selecionadas por javascript para alterar/selecionar o(s) elemento(s) que tenham essa(s) classes.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Fui ver o seu site pessoal. Fantástico. Adorava aprender tocar violino. É uma pena que não tem nenhuma musica no seu site. Talvez é o que falta. Saber que alguém é musico e não ouvir nenuma musica não diz muito. Se adicionar diga para ir ouvir. Cmp

Answer (score 7):

O `span` é apenas um elemento do HTML enquanto a `class` é usada para **manipular** qualquer elemento HTML, como por exemplo, você pode usa-la para estilizar qualquer elemento. Veja:

## CSS

```
.nav {
 background-color: #000;
}
```

## HTML

```
<span class="nav">Texto<span>
<p class="nav">Texto<p>
```

Nesse exemplo, tanto o elemento `p` quanto o `span` vão receber o *background* preto porque tem a `class .nav`

Se você utilizar o elemento `span` para estilizar, todos os elementos `span` vão receber as propriedades do `span`.

Exemplo:

```
span {

  background-color: #fff;

}
```

Você também pode utilizar o `span` para estilizar apenas uma parte de um texto.

Exemplo:

## CSS

```
span {

  color: red;

}
```

## HTML

```
<p>Texto <span>texto vermelho</span> texto.</p>
```

Esse site e bom para estudar `http://www.w3schools.com/`

Comment: Obrigado ana. Já conhecia o site que sugere. Ainda não o sei usar bem admito mas vou fazer o que me diz.

Comment: Um reparo - penso que pudemos usar a class sem o span. Assim desta forma: <p class="lista b">A nossa lista</p> Fica a dúvida.

Comment: Sim, classes podem ser usadas com qualquer elemento html. O spam e' apenas um elemento html.